# Hadoop eclipse plugin : Unable to see output on console

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using hadoop-0.20.2 from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/ and I'm using the following Eclipse plugin hadoop-0.20.1-eclipse-plugin.jar from http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-eclipse-plugin/.

Using the file I'm able to load the file into HDFS and also able to compile word-count program . I'm able to compile it without error and get .class files. But when I run the project on Hadoop, I don't see any out-put on the console.

Please tell me if there are any configurations that I need to get the out-put on  console. Even output file is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should chack the out file path given in  `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));`

Note that the output directory should not exist.

I am running the same example given [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.17.1/mapred_tutorial.html). And it works fine and also creating the output folder.